# Font loading issue in Chrome

Tags: font-awesome

Bootstrap font not loading properly on live server. First second times its loading properly but after several time refresh font not loading properly.Thanks in advance.

**global.scss**

```
@import '../../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Under global.scss, there are no of files i @imported included font-awesome file.

[image]

Comment: Look  for font type (woff,woff2,svg or what?) and check if the proper   mime type is defined on the server e.g. `font/woff`

Comment: Does this problem disappear on the next page reload?

Comment: @Fabian Schöner No it will same...

Comment: Please share the code for how you're including Font Awesome. Also please clarify why you think this is related to Bootstrap? Font Awesome is not packaged with Bootstrap...